# WMI-Activity Event ID5858, ResultCode = 0x80041032 & DCOM Event 10010 timeout errors

Tags: windows-7, event-log, wmi, dcom

I've been trying to eliminate two types of errors for about a month now. First are WMI Event 5858 result code: 0x80041032 and the Second are DCOM Event 10010 server timeout errors. Read 100s of articles and threads - many here. Maybe/likely the 0x80041032 WMI errors are non-sense generated by a canceled request. If true, that's a relief, but would still like to eliminate them if possible ( my OCD :) ). The problem is, this wanta-learn-but-slower-to-absorb retired computer programmer has reached a dead-end.

The following errors occur every boot and before log-in.

```
WMI-Activity EventID 5858:
Id = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}; ClientMachine = DELL-E1705; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 1032; Component = Unknown; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - ROOT\CIMV2 : SELECT * from Win32_ComputerSystem; ResultCode = 0x80041032; PossibleCause = Unknown
Id = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}; ClientMachine = DELL-E1705; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 1032; Component = Unknown; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - ROOT\CIMV2 : SELECT * from Win32_NetworkAdapter; ResultCode = 0x80041032; PossibleCause = Unknown

DistributedCOM EventID 10010:
The server {49BD2028-1523-11D1-AD79-00C04FD8FDFF} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
The server {E2B3C97F-6AE1-41AC-817A-F6F92166D7DD} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

I'm up to here '*' with Component Services, Event Manager, wmidiag, sc, dcomcnfg, and the like. Having difficulty linking the errors to a specific server/AppID/application/driver/dll. For example, the 1st DCOM can't be found anywhere - registry, Component Services, file system. I even booted to a Linux USB and binary/ascii/unicode searched the entire filesystem.

I'm now going around in circles but I hate to give up. Can someone help me out?

Win7Pro updated, home user, SEP, encrypted disk, VPN, network printer, occasional share f/s with a Mac, no odd behaviors, and no virus or malware (used four highly-recommended - 99.99% sure). Careful about installing new apps. Never used a RegCleaner, etc.

Thanks in advance gentlemen.
Mes (aka Mesmurized)